# Should I store my cheese in brine/whey?

Tags: storage-method, cheese

Fresh mozzarella is usually sold floating in whey, and feta cheese is often sold soaking in brine.  Once I've opened the container and used part of the cheese, how should I store it in the fridge to make it keep the best for the greatest time?  Specifically:

1. Should I store the cheeses in liquid, or dry in a covered container?
2. For mozzarella, should I put it away in its original whey, or put it in a clean container with fresh water?
3. For feta, should I store it in the brine it came in, or change the brine before putting it away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either case store the cheese in the liquid it came in, transferring it to a clean container and covering well. Feta lasts reasonably well, but mozzarella only keeps well for a couple of days.

Comment: Given that you're suggesting that I keep the same liquid but change containers, how about at least a bit of justification, either an experiment or a reference?

Comment: Well, if the liquid is good enough to store the cheese at the supermarket, it is surely good enough to store it at home. As for the container, this would depend on what your packaging is like: mozzarella here usually comes in a little bag, so I would _have_ to transfer to a new container. If yours comes in a tub, you could equally well use that. I don't know of any studies (it's not exactly life-changing science after all); my answer comes from experience.

Comment: OK, so you're saying keep it in the original liquid and container if the container is resealable?  Our mozarrella and feta comes in resealable tubs.

Comment: Yes, no point in switching in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...there is no need to change the brine/whey it comes in unless you are planning on trying to store it months after opening it....
Otherwise, for normal storage/useage just leave it in it's original whey or brine which is BALANCED with the cheese in calcium and salt content. If you replace it, will you replace it with a saturated brine which will leach out calcium and increase the saltiness of the cheese? Or perhaps your brine will be less salty, and will still leach out calcium from your cheese as well as salt (and also provide less spoilage protection).

Unless you really know what you are doing (how much cacl2, salt and citric acid to add) you are MUCH better off keeping the original fluid.

Artisan cheesemaker here....